# Is there a special name for a contributed talk given longer time slot?

Tags: conference, cv, presentation, invitations

A conference symposium I'm attending has all contributed talks, no invited or keynote talks.  But in each session, one of the [contributed] talks is given a longer time slot than all the others (40 mins vs 20 mins).  Is there a special name for these types of talks?  How would one denote this on their CV (and should they)?

Comment: If the conference doesn't assign a special designation to the talk, I would not try to do so.

Comment: It might be called the "featured talk" for the session.

Comment: Why the  downvotes?

Comment: Haha, I was wondering the same about the downvotes.  Oh noes, what did I do wrong?!?!

Comment: I'm confident that the conference organizers are using some designated name for these talks among themselves. Ask them what term they use.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a fairly unusual format; I don't think there is a standard name for it that would be recognizable.

If you want to highlight your contribution you could always add some extra description of the content of some sort.

In this case the length of your talk might set it apart, as it implies a bigger contribution to the conference and shows you have experience in doing more than just the typical brief talk:

> "Sproingity Sproing", *International Symposium on Blahdy Blah*, March 2017. (40 minute oral presentation).